# Permissions for PSExec run from SQL job

Tags: sql-server-2008, psexec, sql-job

I have the following in a CMDExec type SQL Job step (details changed):

```
D:\path\PSExec.exe \\servername -accepteula -u "domain\username" -p password D:\path\executable.exe
```

This works fine.
However, I have set up a proxy in SQL Server for the same user account - which the job is using, so you'd think I wouldn't need the -u and -p arguments.
But if I don't supply them I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

which is from SQL Server, because the remote executable connects to SQL as the same user context.

Why doesn't this work, and can I make it work without including the credentials in the job detail? (or a batch file, or similar)

Thanks

P.S. The SQL Server connected to by the remote executable is the same one as the job is run in, if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because Kerberos is not running!

Thanks to Marc Jellinek on LinkedIn SQLDBA group :)

Comment: I've linked back to this post from a more recent question here, where scenario is different, but the error message is the same:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871816/how-to-run-an-r-script-which-has-database-connection-using-integrated-windows-a/47877987#47877987